# How to make gfortran case insensitive for reading filenames

Tags: fortran, filenames, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am new to gfortran, and I am trying to compile an atmospheric code that draws from numerous different files. The issue, however, is that some of the files used for input parameters are in different cases than what is needed in the main files.

I can edit the name of each file individually as needed, but there are hundreds of files and that would be tedious. Is there a way, like an optimization option, to make it insensitive of case in files?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and also resding [ask]. Which operating system this is on?

Comment: Remember that operating systems and dhells have various commands and utilities that can automate file renanibg.

Comment: Case-sensitivity would be irrelevant in Windows, so I presume you are running in linux. It would be far better done outside of your program by the operating system shells. However, if you really had to do it programmatically then: call an operating system command to list the bare (filename) contents of the directory to a file; read the individual filenames and convert to a consistent (say, lower) case; identify the one you want and open it. But that is unnecessarily hard work: use a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If the operating system and the file system are case sensitive, thrn gfortran uses the system services to open files. You can even have two different files that differ only in the case of some of the characters in the file names.

The best solution is to automate your renaming process.

What you could also do is to code a routine that searches the directory for files that conform to your requirements. Looping over files in  a directory is possible, but not in pure Fortran. One must call some system routines, e.g., as done in https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/utils/file_names.c with the corresponding Fortran interfaces in the file_names module in https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/utils/eaf2vtk.f90

Finally, if the difference is simple - only all lower case, only all upper case, or only first upper case, you could try to open all combinations in your Fortran code.

Overall, these programmatic solutions will be more work than just renaming the files. But they can be also used in future.